# Sending more than 32 bytes between raspberry and arduino

Tags: python, i2c, arduino

I'm working in a project and I need to send more than 32 bytes from Raspberry Pi 3 to Arduino and viceversa.

My first question is: Why this limit of 32 bytes on SMBus? There is some technical reason?

I can't find any good solution about this.

My second question is: Which is the best way to transfer more than 32 bytes between the 2 devices via I2C using SMBus or other? Using some kind of custom protocol?

An example is well accepted.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Send 32 bytes at a time, in sequence.

Have a look at the [TLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) format for an easy way to make a custom protocol.

There are several python packages to help you set up an encoder and a parser, for example [construct](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/construct) or [Simple TLV Parser](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/533137-simple-tlv-parser/), but if you want to keep it simple, you can probably build your own in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

SMBus does have a 32 byte limit.  I2C has no limit.  It may be because SMBus has timeouts whereas I2C doesn't, but that's just me thinking out loud.

A solution is to use I2C rather than SMBus.

There are a variety of ways to use I2C rather than SMBus from Python.

As I wrote pigpio I will point out that one of the simplest is to use the [pigpio Python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) module and the [i2c_read_device](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#i2c_read_device) and [i2c_write_device](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#i2c_write_device) methods.